# Does Nicotine Trigger a Relaxation Response?

Tags: nicotine, relax-relaxation

If I read [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19878666) correctly it indicates nicotine triggers a relaxation response in rabbits. Do we know whether a similar response is triggered in humans? Is this relaxation response the same [relaxation response Lissa Rankin states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWQfe__fNbs&feature=youtu.be&t=800) explains much of the placebo effect?

**Note:**  The YouTube video is set to start at the relevant segment and is only about 3 minutes long

If you'd prefer a link to literature rather than a video clip, Rankin refers to Herbert Benson. A relevant paper is [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00332747.1974.11023785?journalCode=upsy20) and a book is [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380006766).

My layman summation of Lissa Rankin's point: When a relaxation response is activated, mental stress in the body is reduced and chemicals like oxytocin, dopamine, and endorphins are released. Certain natural healing mechanisms flourish in this state. Placebo effects basically result from an activation of this relaxation response, but you can also do things like meditate or get a massage to tap into that relaxation response to some extent.

Comment: You started out with a good question but then came the youtube video. Can you please find a text explanation of Lissa Rankin's presentation? Asking readers to spend 18 minutes watching a video to understand your question isn't reasonable.

Comment: First of all, I didn't ask anyone to watch a video. It may well be that (in fact I'm counting on the fact that) experts here are already familiar with Rankin, Benson, and/or the Relaxation Response. Secondly, I don't know why an 18 minute video would be unreasonable when reading through the literature takes much more time. Third, I set the time in the video link so that it does not start from the beginning; the relevant segment is only about 3 minutes. Fourth, I added my layman summation and some additional literature.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. The defensive reaction really isn't necessary.